# How do you use knockout.js to build a <select> element's <option>s with both text and values, and also set an initially-selected value?

Tags: knockout.js, binding, html-select, default

I'm using knockout.js to build a `<select>` element's `<option>`s, and also to set its default-selected value.  All works as expected *until* I add `optionsValue` binding, at which point the dropdown no longer shows the proper initial value on page load.

In other words, this works:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedAccount, options: accounts, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

...but this doesn't work:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedAccount, options: accounts, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
```

Here's my simplified, complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src='knockout-2.1.0.debug.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select data-bind="value: selectedAccount, options: accounts, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
        <script>
            function QuickTransferViewmodel()
            {
                var self = this;

                self.accounts =
                [
                    { id: 0, name: "Spending" },
                    { id: 1, name: "Savings" }
                ];

                self.selectedAccount = ko.observable(self.accounts[1]);
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new QuickTransferViewmodel());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would expect the dropdown to show "Savings" as selected by default.  It only does so if I remove the optionsValue binding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly related to your questions, but you may get some unusual results if the `value` binding is before `options`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `optionsValue` binding is used to determine which property is used to set the `value` attribute on the generated `option` elements.

This one-line change makes your sample work for me:

`self.selectedAccount = ko.observable(1);`

Your `value` binding is set to `selectedAccount` which is an ID, and the values in your generated `options` elements are indeed the IDs.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  That makes sense.  In the knockout.js documentation and tutorial, they don't use optionsValue binding.  I suppose that in the absence of specified option-values, knockout.js automatically tracks the value as references to items in the options-bound array.  But as you've pointed out, this works differently if you specify an optionsValue binding.  That's why my code worked only when optionsValue was left out.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the "value" one of the ones in the list of options.....

I ended up writing some coffeescript to handle this....

```
 replaceWithMatchingExt = (observableToFind, observablePropertyToSet, list, match) -> 
    return if not observablePropertyToSet
    return if not observableToFind()
    return if list.length == 0
    observablePropertyToSet (x for x in list when x[match]() == observableToFind()[match]())[0] 

replaceWithMatching = (prop, list, match) ->
    replaceWithMatchingExt(prop, prop, list, match)
```

which then allows me to ( also coffeescript ... )

```
replaceWithMatching @Product, @Products(), 'Id'
```

given that Product is the value, Products is the list of choices.... and 'Id' is the property I want to match on.   ie, Id is what I can use to work out equivalent Products.

The code then replaces the observable Product with an object that's in the Products list if it matches one.